# Play framework - How can I mock the render() method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, playframework

I want to write a pure unit test for a method in my controller. The method calls render() on the base class (play.mvc.Controller) which I want to mock out.

I am not sure what is the best way to mock out this inheritance dependency.

Is there a well defined way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is no easy way to do this. render() is defined as static() so you can't override it in an anonymous class inside the test.

So I decided to move out my business logic into a separate service class which I can test more easily. The controller is now very thin and doesn't do much.